# How to execute PowerShell script and launch .exe in Dockerfile entrypoint?

Tags: windows, docker, powershell

I need to execute **PowerShell**-script and after launch `nginx.exe` in my **Windows**-container, so I've added an entrypoint to my **Dockerfile** as below:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "C:\nginx\Configure-Nginx.ps1 && C:\nginx\nginx.exe"]
```

But it doesn't work.

I am noobie with **PowerShell**... How to make it correctly?

Comment: In principle (may not solve all of your problems): `powershell.exe` is the CLI of _Windows PowerShell_, where the pipeline-chaining `&&` operator isn't supported (it requires PowerShell (Core) v7+; PowerShell (Core)'s CLI is `pwsh.exe`). To emulate `&&`, use `C:\nginx\Configure-Nginx.ps1; if ($?) { C:\nginx\nginx.exe }`

Comment: Also, I think you must _escape the backslashes_ in your array elements -> `ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "C:\\nginx\\Configure-Nginx.ps1; if ($?) { C:\\nginx\\nginx.exe }"]`

Comment: Thank you for comments, I've check my **PowerShell** version, you're right, I use **5.1**, it doesn't support `&&` operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see here you want to do two things:

1. Run powershell script before container starts
2. Do an entrypoint runing nginx from powershell

It translates to this:

```
CMD [ "powershell", "-c", "C:\nginx\Configure-Nginx.ps1" ]

ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "C:\nginx\nginx.exe"]
```

Comment: Will `Configure-Nginx.ps1` execute on `docker run` or `docker build`? I need it was on `docker run`.

Comment: I've posted a new little modified question that is more detailed. I hope it will help to understand my problem.

Comment: Modified answer again :)